# Proving $c_1(\mathcal{L})\cap[X] = [Y]$ for submanifold $Y\subset X$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold of complex dimension $n$, and let $Y$ be a complex submanifold of codimension 1. It's easy to show that both $X$ and $Y$ are orientable. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a nontrivial line bundle on $X$, and let $c_1(\mathcal{L})\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ denote the first chern class of $\mathcal{L}$. Let $[X]$ and $[Y]$ denote the orientation classes of X and Y respectively. Note that $[X]\in H_{2n}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, while $[Y]\in H_{2n-2}(Y,\mathbb{Z}).$

How does one prove that $c_1(\mathcal{L})\cap[X] = [Y]$, where $\cap$ denotes the cap product? I tried to argue from definition of cap product, but it seems that I don't have a good description of [X]. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't think that is true, it depends on the line bundle. For example if the line bundle is trivial then your equation can't hold.

Comment: @JohnMa: You're right. Actually in my original problem $\mathcal{L}$ is coming from an effective Cartier divisor; but I think taking $\mathcal{L}$ nontrivial should be enough, since only principal divisors give trivial bundle, and the only Cartier divisor on a compact manifold which is both effective and principal is a global holomorphic function, which must be constant. I've edited the question.

Comment: For this to be right, $\mathcal L$ needs to be the line bundle $\mathscr O_X(Y)$ associated to the divisor $Y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin : You're absolutely right, in my original problem the line bundle is of the form you mentioned. Can you please explain more, or maybe at least give some reference for this? I've wasted a lot of time on it, I'd really appreciate your help at this stage.

Comment: Griffith and Harris PAG, p.141 assertion 2 in the proposition @yojusmath